# Improper integration of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\{|B|^{2}e^{-\frac{t^{2}}{w^{2}}}\}dt$

Tags: calculus

Yesterday, when I was trying to solve an improper integration which has a horrible form like $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tan^{-1}\{|B|^{2}e^{-\frac{T^{2}}{w^{2}}}\}dt$$, which is a part of my problem i was trying. After using by parts, I have managed to made it simple like $$\int_0^\infty {\frac{t^{1/2}e^{-t}}{ae^{-t}+e^{t}}dt}$$ where $a=|B|^{4}$, $t=\frac{T^{2}}{w^{2}}$ (I have removed the constant part which is outside of integral sign). Now, seeing $t^{1/2}e^{-t}$, I thought it could be done by application of Gamma function. Whereas I couldn't find a way to do it. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.($B,w$ are constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_0^\infty {\frac{t^{1/2}e^{-t}}{ae^{-t}+e^{t}}dt}
=
-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{a 2^{3/2}}\;\mathrm{Li}_{3/2}(-a)
$$
using the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$
\mathrm{Li}_{s}(z) := \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k^s}
$$
The method is expand in a geometric series
$$
\frac{t^{1/2}e^{-t}}{ae^{-t}+e^{t}} = 
t^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}a^{k-1}e^{-2kt}
$$
and integrate term-by-term.